# cant access $db codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, autoload

I have:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

and in a Model called teams, I have this inside of a function:

```
$query = $this->db->query("Select * from Teams");
```

But I get this error:
Message: Undefined property: Teams::$db

But if I do this:

```
$CI =& get_instance();           
$query = $CI->db->query("Select * from Teams");
```

it works. I shouldnt have to load CI. How do I get around this?

Comment: Can you post the full source of your model class?

Comment: Without seeing the code, I'm going to guess you have a `__construct()` method in your model that does not call `parent::__construct()`.

Answer (score 1):

cant understand you problem but model file name in lower case ex team_model.php and class
name start with Capital latter ex

```
class Team_model extends CI_Model {}
```

or please full code to understand problem